# Using Hbase REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, hbase

I'm researching on Hbase REST API for my use case. I have a JSON file on a machine which is outside of Hbase cluster(No hbase client installed).

Requirement is to put the file in Hbase Table with below columns.

```
Rec_Id  File_Id  Meggase  Timestamp
```

**File_Id:** This will be file name

**Message:** Contains content of JSON file

Is it possible to do this with Hbase Rest API? If not what will be other solution. Please direct me to any good link

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-use-the-apache-hbase-rest-interface-part-1/) link to understand HBase with REST cleint like creating table, adding and getting rows. Its all about mapping from jason field to Hbase column qualifier. Happy learning

Comment: I want to store entire JSON file content in  Message field of Hbase table is it possible ?